# Como remover uma coluna do data.frame em R?

Tags: r, data.frame

Suponha um data.frame genérico, tal como:

```
set.seed(1)
dados <- data.frame(y=rnorm(100), x= rnorm(100), z=rnorm(100), w=rnorm(100))
head(dados)
           y           x          z          w
1 -0.6264538 -0.62036668  0.4094018  0.8936737
2  0.1836433  0.04211587  1.6888733 -1.0472981
3 -0.8356286 -0.91092165  1.5865884  1.9713374
4  1.5952808  0.15802877 -0.3309078 -0.3836321
5  0.3295078 -0.65458464 -2.2852355  1.6541453
6 -0.8204684  1.76728727  2.4976616  1.5122127
```

Como faço para excluir colunas do data.frame?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Há várias formas de se fazer isso.

A mais simples é atribuir `NULL` à coluna, por exemplo, para remover a coluna `x`:

```
dados$x <- NULL
head(dados)
           y          z          w
1 -0.6264538  0.4094018  0.8936737
2  0.1836433  1.6888733 -1.0472981
3 -0.8356286  1.5865884  1.9713374
4  1.5952808 -0.3309078 -0.3836321
5  0.3295078 -2.2852355  1.6541453
6 -0.8204684  2.4976616  1.5122127
```

Também é possível deletar várias de uma vez colocando o sinal de menos nas colunas que você não quer que sejam selecionadas, por exemplo, para excluir a primeira e terceira coluna:

```
dados<-dados[,-c(1,3)]
head(dados)
            x          w
1 -0.62036668  0.8936737
2  0.04211587 -1.0472981
3 -0.91092165  1.9713374
4  0.15802877 -0.3836321
5 -0.65458464  1.6541453
6  1.76728727  1.5122127
```

Outra forma é referenciar as colunas pelo nome, criando um vetor de colunas a serem excluídas e deixando no data.frame apenas aquelas colunas que não estão neste vetor:

```
excluir <- c("x", "y")
dados <- dados[,!(names(dados)%in% excluir)]
head(dados)
       z          w
1  0.4094018  0.8936737
2  1.6888733 -1.0472981
3  1.5865884  1.9713374
4 -0.3309078 -0.3836321
5 -2.2852355  1.6541453
6  2.4976616  1.5122127
```

Answer (score 4):

Para remover apenas uma coluna, eu prefiro o modo utilizado pelo @carloscinelli

```
dados$x <- NULL
head(dados)
           y          z          w
1 -0.6264538  0.4094018  0.8936737
2  0.1836433  1.6888733 -1.0472981
3 -0.8356286  1.5865884  1.9713374
4  1.5952808 -0.3309078 -0.3836321
5  0.3295078 -2.2852355  1.6541453
6 -0.8204684  2.4976616  1.5122127
```

Já para os demais casos, prefiro usar o comando `subset`

Para manter as colunas `x` e `w`, use:

```
dados <- subset(dados, select = c(x, w))
head(dados)
            x          w
1 -0.62036668  0.8936737
2  0.04211587 -1.0472981
3 -0.91092165  1.9713374
4  0.15802877 -0.3836321
5 -0.65458464  1.6541453
6  1.76728727  1.5122127
```

para excluir as colunas `x` e `y`, use o sinal `-` antes do vetor com os nomes das colunas

```
dados <- subset(dados, select = -c(x, y))
head(dados)
           z          w
1  0.4094018  0.8936737
2  1.6888733 -1.0472981
3  1.5865884  1.9713374
4 -0.3309078 -0.3836321
5 -2.2852355  1.6541453
6  2.4976616  1.5122127
```

Vale a pena uma observação quanto ao uso do operador `[]`. Para manter apenas a coluna `w` podemos usar:

```
excluir <- c("x", "y", "z")
dados <- dados[,!(names(dados) %in% excluir)]
head(dados)
[1]  0.8936737 -1.0472981  1.9713374 -0.3836321  1.6541453  1.5122127
```

mas nesse caso `dados` é transformado em um *vetor*. Para corrigir use o parâmatro `drop = FALSE`

```
dados <- dados[,!(names(dados) %in% excluir), drop = FALSE]
head(dados)
           w
1  0.8936737
2 -1.0472981
3  1.9713374
4 -0.3836321
5  1.6541453
6  1.5122127
```

ou, se preferir usar `subset`

```
dados <- subset(dados, select = c(w))
head(dados)
           w
1  0.8936737
2 -1.0472981
3  1.9713374
4 -0.3836321
5  1.6541453
6  1.5122127
```

Comment: `drop=FALSE` é mágico, fiquei uns bons anos fazendo códigos que tinham que se adaptar entre data.frame/matrizes e vetores pq eu queria ora uma coluna e ora mais de uma...

Answer (score 2):

Olá. Eu costumo usar o comando `select`:

```
install.packages("dplyr")
library(dplyr)

dados = dados %>%
  select(x, y, z)
```

Usando seu exemplo, eu uso o `select` para selecionar somente as colunas que me interessam. Para exemplificar eu não selecionei a coluna `w`. Isso faz que a coluna `w` seja excluída.

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 0):

Com o pacote data.table também é possível.

```
set.seed(1)
dados <- data.frame(y=rnorm(100), x= rnorm(100), z=rnorm(100), w=rnorm(100))
library(data.table)
df <- data.table::as.data.table(dados)
df2 <- df[, names(df)[c(-1)], with = FALSE]
head(df2, 5)
```

- Note que ao utilizar `names(df)[c(-1)]` eu elimino a primeira coluna do `df`.

```
> head(d2f, 5)
             x          z          w
1: -0.62036668  0.4094018  0.8936737
2:  0.04211587  1.6888733 -1.0472981
3: -0.91092165  1.5865884  1.9713374
4:  0.15802877 -0.3309078 -0.3836321
5: -0.65458464 -2.2852355  1.6541453
```

- Com `names(df)[c(-2, -3)]` as colunas `x` e `z` são eliminadas a partir da informação de `df`.

```
df3 <- df[, names(df)[c(-2, -3)], with = FALSE]
head(df3, 5)
```

```
> head(df3, 5)
            y          w
1: -0.6264538  0.8936737
2:  0.1836433 -1.0472981
3: -0.8356286  1.9713374
4:  1.5952808 -0.3836321
5:  0.3295078  1.6541453
```

Answer (score 0):

Todas as respostas dadas solucionam o problema. Mas, considere isso:

- um banco de dados com muitas variáveis (ex. 50 +);
- que existam múltiplas classes de variáveis (`numeric`, `character`...);
- que estas variáveis estejam fora de ordem (ex. duas numéricas seguidas de uma variável de classe caracter e assim por diante).

A melhor alternativa nestes casos é realizar o procedimento pela **classe** do objeto, não pelos seus nomes ou índices.

Tomando emprestado o banco de dados da pergunta e adicionando mais uma variável (`k`), a qual é de classe `character`, temos:

```
dados <- data.frame(y=rnorm(100), x= rnorm(100), z=rnorm(100), w=rnorm(100), 
                k = rep(c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'), times = 2, each = 10), 
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

head(dados)

           y          z          w k
1 -1.5570357  1.5468813  0.8500435 a
2  1.9231637  0.1789210 -0.9253130 a
3 -1.8568296 -0.2825466  0.8935812 a
4 -2.1061184 -0.7672988 -0.9410097 a
5  0.6976485 -0.5764042  0.5389521 a
6  0.9074444 -0.9148558 -0.1819744 a
```

A função `select_if` (`dplyr`) soluciona este problema ao analisar *apenas* as classes dos vetores do `data.frame`.

Suponha que eu queira eliminar todas as variáveis de classe `numeric`:

```
library(tidyverse)

dados %>% 
  select_if(negate(is.numeric)) %>% 
  head()

  k
1 a
2 a
3 a
4 a
5 a
6 a
```

Fazer isso evita escrever "nome por nome" ou procurar os índices de forma manual de cada uma das variáveis a serem eliminadas.

Answer (score 0):

Infelizmente `dados<-dados[,-c(1,3)]`não funcionou pra mim. Já `dados <- subset(dados, select = -c(x, y)`) funcionou perfeitamente mas precisei tirar as aspas.